# Light switch for multiple fixtures feels warm after a while

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, switch

I have a light switch that handles 4 chandeliers (3 60 watts bulbs) and two ceiling fans.  If switch is on for awhile it is warm to the touch.  Should I install a heavier switch?

Comment: Is it a regular light switch or a dimmer?

Comment: @Tyson lights and fans on one switch so I doubt it is a dimmer

Comment: @manassehkatz you’d be surprised what pops up in the wild.  I’ve seen people put single circuit fan/light combos on dimmers before... because they don’t know better.  And then sometimes the problem even survives ownership or tenant change.

Comment: Or one place I know of recently where lights were upgraded to LEDs and split into 2 circuits and instead of replacing 1 regular switch with 2 regular switches, they put in 2 slide dimmers. Which was totally stupid because I know these particular lights would never be used dimmed even if they could be (trust me on this) and the dimming doesn't work anyway because the particular LEDs aren't dimmable. So yeah, there is a lot of crazy stuff out there...

Comment: 3 60 watt bulbs is 180 watts.  (why are you still using those???)  4 chandeliers is then 720W, plus say 100W for each of 2 fans = 920W, or about 8 amps. Yeah, that's more than the $1 light switches are made for.  Get a quality one.

Answer (score 2):

Unlikely that the switch isn't heavy duty enough. But the contacts in the switch and/or the connections to the wires may have problems. I suggest replacing the switch just in case it is having internal problems. When you do that, check the wires for any evidence of arcing. If the wires are not in good shape, cut off the end and strip a new section to attach to the screw terminals on the new switch. Obviously turn off the circuit at the breaker before doing any of this.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have a standard 15 amp switch, and probably the cheap one to boot (Standard vs Preferred, as Leviton likes to call it). It could be worth going up to at least the beefier switch. I doubt you need a 20 amp here.